# How to add an empty component in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I need to press two buttons down in the screen. Is not there such a component (spacer) which would have 100% height and moved the buttons to the bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tool bar for that purpose which put all the content into the bottom of the view
https://framework7.io/docs/toolbar.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try it